# Mutually Exclusive Team City Build Triggers Both Firing

Tags: version-control, build, tfs, teamcity, build-automation

We have two separate builds configured in TeamCity against TFS with the following triggers (listed below).

```
Build 1:
+:Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/FilePrefix\*\*
+:Source/\*\*
+:Tests/\*\*

Build 2:
+:Folder1/Folder2/\*\*
-:Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/FilePrefix\*\*
-:Tests/\*\*
-:Source/\*\*
```

If we make a change to a file in `Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/FilePrefix` we are finding that BOTH builds trigger. [The documentation states](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-TriggerRulesExample):

> For each file in a change the most specific rule is found (the rule
>   matching the longest file path). The build is triggered if there is at
>   least one file with a matching "include" rule or a file with no
>   matching rules.

Doesn't this mean that only the most specific rule takes precedence? Why isn't Build 2 excluding this file because of the `-:Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/FilePrefix**`? It seems like the `+:Folder1/Folder2/**` is overriding the ignore rule.

Comment: We ended up working around the issue and never found the true answer.

Comment: It's been a while and I had a similar problem. I worked around it using so called "Shared Resources" in TeamCity (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Shared+Resources) and defined a quota which both builds then locked at build start (using Build Feature https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Adding+Build+Features). Thjat way we ensured that not BOTH builds run at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this a few weeks ago and found that we had to specify the final wildcard as a '.' instead of a '*' for negation statements.

So your trigger rules for build2 would end up looking like:

```
+:Folder1/Folder2/\*\.
-:Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/FilePrefix\*\.
-:Tests/\*\.
-:Source/\*\.
```